# Disable React Native Webview text selection loupe on iPad

Tags: textselection, react-native-webview, magnification, loupe, ipados15

**Setup:** Our RN (0.61.5) app is using `react-native webview@8.0.6` to display content and interact with the user. The app includes some text input fields, swipe guestures, buttons, longpress actions. As of iPad os 15.1 a text selection magnifier has been reintroduced in the OS.

**Problem:** The little text selection magnifier capsule is popping up on every long-press inside the Webview. It happens on divs, icons, text, does not matter what you press. `user-select: none;` does not seem to affect it as well. It's been set for the body of the document which results in no text getting selected, but magnifier still shows up every time. Does not break anything but our app does not benefit from it either.

**Question:** Is there any way to disable this new text-select magnifier for the Webview?

Thanks